# What does the "ordered" flag on the WCF Server do in reliable sessions?

Tags: wcf, server, configuration, client, reliablesession

I understand what the "ordered" flag on the client side does.....but does the server side config do anything? I know comms will work irrespective of whether the "ordered" flag is set to "true" or "false".
Is it a redundanct setting for the server side?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of "ordered" in the Microsoft documentation is as follows:

```
You specify the ordered delivery assurances for the reliable session by setting the ordered attribute to true.
```

This attribute indicates whether the server will process the messages in the order in which the client sends messages. For example, if the sequence of the client calling service operations is Step1-Step2-Step3, then the server will also receive messages in this order. Setting it to false does not Will affect the operation of the service, it only indicates  the server whether to process according to the order in which the client sends messages.

**So it is not a redundant setting, you can set it according to your requirement.**

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: So if on the **client** side the ordered is set to "true", we know it will sequentially send requests to the server in order (Step1-Step2-Step3).


However if on the **server** side ordered is set to "false", it might process the requests out of sequence (Step3-Step1-Step2) but if its set to "true" then it will process them in order (Step1-Step2-Step3)

Comment: Yes.The configuration of the client is based on the server, if the server is set to true, the client also needs to be set to true.

Comment: Ah. So even though its possible to have both the client and server configured to be different values (which i have tried and seems to work), they should be the same

Comment: In order for the client and server to successfully communicate in WCF, the server configuration needs to be the same as the client configuration. I think this may be because the "ordered" attribute does not affect server communication.

Comment: All configurations are subject to server configuration.

Comment: You mentioned "I think this may be because the "ordered" attribute does not affect server communication"
That is what i specifically what i wanted to know.
Whether or not the "ordered" attribute does anything on the server side

Comment: The "order" attribute simply means whether the server receives messages from the client in order.

Comment: No matter you set "order" to false or true, it will not affect normal communication.